# How to create a layer above the background image in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmUxP.jpg)

How do I partially cover the background image with another layout where I can put other items like another image or Textviews etc. Exactly like the picture I posted.

Comment: Unclear. What are you asking, really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean layering multiple views above each other. To achieve this, have the views inside a `FrameLayout`, for example. Each child view of a `ViewGroup` is rendered above the preceding child view. For more details, read the Android Training docs section about [how Android draws views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).